# Sketch f(x,y)=(21/4)x^2y over the region x^2 <= y <= 1

Tags: matlab

Can someone share a technique using MATLAB to plot the surface f(x,y)=(21/4)x^2y over the region x^2 <=  y <= 1?

Also, if anyone is aware of some tutorials or links that would help with this type of problem, could you please share them?

Thanks.

Here is another approach:

```
%%
close all
x=linspace(-1,1,40);
g1=x.^2;
g2=ones(1,40);
y=[];
n=20;
for k=0:n
    y=[y;g1+(g2-g1)*k/n];
end
x=x(ones(1,n+1),:);
z=21/4*x.^2.*y;
meshz(x,y,z)
axis tight
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
view(136,42)
```

And the result:

[image]

And finally, you can map the region (-1,1)x(0,1) in the uv-plane into the region bounded by $y=x^2 and y=1 in the xy-plane with the parametrization:

f(u,v) = (u\sqrt{v},v)

Capture from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823168/transform-rectangular-region-to-region-bounded-by-y-1-and-y-x2

This code produces the same image shown above:

```
close all
[u,v]=meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,40),linspace(0,1,20));
x=u.*sqrt(v);
y=v;
z=21/4*x.^2.*y;
meshz(x,y,z)
axis tight
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
view(136,42)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's look at your valid region of values.  This is telling us that `y >= x^2` and also `y <= 1`.  This means that your y values need to be on the positive plane bounded by the parabola `x^2` and they also must be less than or equal to 1.  In other words, your `y` values must be bound within the area dictated from `y = x^2` to `y = 1`.  Pictorially, your `y` values are bounded within this shape:

[image]

As such, your `x` values must also be bound between -1 and 1.  Therefore, your actual boundaries are: `-1 <= x <= 1` and `0 <= y <= 1`.  However, this only locates our boundaries for `x` and `y` but it doesn't handle where the plot has valid values.  We'll tackle that later.

Now that we have that established, you can use `ezsurf` to plot surface plots in MATLAB that are dictated by a 2D equation.

You call `ezsurf` like so:

```
ezsurf(FUN, [XMIN,XMAX,YMIN,YMAX]);
```

`FUN` is a function or a **string** that contains the equation you want, and `XMIN,XMAX,YMIN,YMAX` contain the lowest and highest `x` and `y` values you want to plot.  Plotting without these values assumes a span from `-2*pi` to `2*pi` in both dimensions.  As such, let's create a new function that will handle when we have valid values, and when we don't.  Use this code, and save it to a new file called `myfun.m`.  Make sure you save this to your current **Working Directory**.

```
function z = myfun(x,y)
    z = (21/4)*x.^2.*y;
    z(~(x.^2 <= y & y <= 1)) = nan;
end
```

This will allow you to take a series of `x` and `y` values and output values that are dictated by the 2D equation that you have given us.  Any values that don't satisfy the condition of `x^2 <= y <= 1`, you set them to `NaN`.  `ezsurf` will not plot `NaN` values.

Now, call `ezsurf` like so:

```
ezsurf(@myfun, [-1,1,0,1]);
```

You thus get:

[image]

This will spawn a new figure for you, and there are some tools at the top that will allow you interact with your 3D plot.  For instance, you can use the rotation tool that's at the top bar beside the **hand** to rotate your figure around and see what this looks like.  Click on this tool, then left click your mouse and hold the left mouse button anywhere within the surface plot.  You can drag around, changing the azimuth and the latitude to get the perspective that you want.

## Edit: June 4th, 2014

Noting your comments, we can decrease the *jagged edges* by increasing the number of points in the plot.  As such, you can append a final parameter to `ezsurf` which is `N`, the number of points to add in each dimension.  Increasing the number of points will decrease the width in between each point and so the plot will look smoother.  The default value of `N` is 60 in both dimensions.  Let's try increasing the amount of points in each dimension to 100.

```
ezsurf(@myfun, [-1,1,0,1], 100);
```

Your plot will look like:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can `ezsurf` restrict the plot to the region x^2 <= y <= 1?

Comment: @Steve Not that I am aware of.  You need to manually place where to restrict the plot by solving where it is bounded *a priori*.  If you want to do it programatically, your approach is better.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah your approach is correct.  I'm not properly restricting the values.  I'll edit my post to try and fix it.

Comment: Is there some sort of parametric approach that will eliminate the jagged edges?

Comment: @David: You can increase the resolution of the plot by increasing the number of points within the surface plot.  Unfortunately when you're plotting on a computer, you have to go with a discrete number of points.  The smaller the width in between neighbouring points, the more continuous your plot will look.  As such, you can call `ezsurf` with a final parameter `N`, specifying how many points in each dimension you want.  The default value is 60, so there are 60 points in the `x` and `y` direction.  Try increasing this to like 100 to smooth your plot.  Do this: `ezsurf(@myfun, [-1,1,0,1], 100);`

Comment: @David: I have edited my post to accommodate for your comments.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This is definitely a really well written answer, and one that I will study quite closely in order to aid my students next semester. I will post another approach in my question area.

Comment: @David I'm glad to help.  If you feel that this question has benefited you, please consider accepting my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to make the required function, compute the values, and plot only the region that is desired:

```
% Make the function. You could put this in a file by itself, if you wanted.
f = @(x,y) (21/4)*x.^2.*y;

[X Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1));
Z = f(X,Y);

% compute the values we want to plot:
valsToPlot = (X.^2 <= Y) & (Y <= 1);

% remove the values that we don't want to plot:
X(~valsToPlot)   = nan;
Y(~valsToPlot)   = nan;
Z(~valsToPlot)   = nan;

% And... plot.
figure(59382);
clf;

surf(X,Y,Z);
```